# setting js simple cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I've been out of web development for a while now so very rusty.
I need to make a cookie

1. If the user visits the site > set cookie
2. If user comes back to site > read cookie
3. If time since user last arrived is less than 24hrs > set the ID of a div to style="display:none;"

im struggling and would really appreciate some guidance.

thanks so much

Comment: What language are you looking to implement this in? Server side, or JavaScript?

Comment: javascript thanks code duck...

just trying to keep it real simple

Answer (score 1):

With JavaScript you can
- read cookie:

```
var coo = [],
    a;
if(document.cookie != ''){
    $.each(document.cookie.split('; '), function(i, val){
        a = val.split('=');
        coo[a[0]] = a[1];
    });
}
```

here we have a `coo` with all cookies (`coo['Cookie1'] == 'value'`).
- set cookie:

```
document.cookie = 'Cookie_1='+'value for this cookie';
```

BTW code is using jQuery for $.each.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the messy solution i cam up with in case anyone wanted to know:

```
function nameDefined(ckie,nme)
```

{
   var splitValues
   var i
   for (i=0;i
      tvalue=getCookieValue(nvpair,cname)  //Gets the value of the cookie
      if (tvalue == cvalue) return true
       else return false
   }
   else return false
}
function redirectLink() {
    if (testCookie("here10", "yes")) {
     //window.location="here.html"      //Go to the location indicating the user has been here
       //alert("there");
       window.document.getElementById("indicator").style.display = "none";
   }
   else{
       //alert(" not there");
       var futdate = new Date()     //Get the current time and date
      var expdate = futdate.getTime()  //Get the milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970
      expdate += 10000  //expires in 1 hour(milliseconds)
      futdate.setTime(expdate)
      var newCookie="here10=yes; path=/;"   //Set the new cookie values up
      newCookie += " expires=" + futdate.toGMTString()
      window.document.cookie=newCookie //Write the cookie
      // window.location="not.html"     //Go to the location indicating the user has not been here

```
  window.document.getElementById("indicator").style.display = "block";
```

}
}